# How to create a plot one below the other using dot graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm able to create a graph in the same row using dot graphviz. I want to create graphs one below the other i.e. after plotting one subgraph it should go to next line and then start plotting the next graph..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalist code for `dot`. The subgraph "plot2" is below "plot1" because `rankdir=LR`.

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR

  subgraph cluster_2 {
    a2
    label="plot2"
  }

  subgraph cluster_1 {
    a1
    label="plot1";
  }
}
```

You can test it directly here: [GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1413401857595#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a2%0A%20%20%20%20label%3D%22plot2%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a1%0A%20%20%20%20label%3D%22plot1%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)